# Simple Focus Listener in Java

Tags: java, swing, focus, jpanel, graphics2d

I have created a simple application with a Panel(extended by JPanel) which contains a small box(myMessagePanel - see the code below).

Basically, I want to generate focusevents from both the Panel and the box when the box is pressed. However, only focusGained and focusLost in the Panel is called. Here is the code:

myMessageBox is the box, Panel is the panel and FocusListenerTest contains the main

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Panel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, FocusListener {
myMessageBox msgBox;

public Panel() {
    addMouseListener(this);
    addFocusListener(this);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    msgBox = new myMessageBox(g);
    g.dispose();
}

public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
    System.out.println("Focus gained in JPanel");
}

public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe){
    System.out.println("Focus lost in JPanel");
}       

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    requestFocus();
    System.out.println("Mouse Pressed in JPanel");
}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {}
}

class myMessageBox extends Component implements FocusListener, MouseListener{
myMessageBox(Graphics g) {
    addMouseListener(this);
    addFocusListener(this);
    paintComponent(g);
    System.out.println("Done");
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.fillRect(150,100,100,100);
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    requestFocus();
    System.out.println("Mouse pressed on box");
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {}

public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe){
    System.out.println("Focus gained by box");
}

public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
    System.out.println("Focus lost by box");
}
}

public class FocusListenertest {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    Panel content = new Panel();
    window.setContentPane(content);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setLocation(100,75);
    window.setSize(400, 400);
    window.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

When I run this code, "Focus gained by box" is not printed when the myMessageBox is pressed.

Thanks

(PS: Didn't write comments as it is a simple application. Please let me know if comments are required)

Comment: add `msgBox` to `Panel`. Also No bounds set for the Component.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, there is no `msgBox` on your panel - it is just drawn over a panel, but from the structure's point of view, it does not exist at all. You need to add `msgBox` to the panel's children list, using standart JPanel's `add` method. Your `myMessageBox` class must inherit a `JComponent` from Swing, not `Component` from AWT, then your `paintComponent` method will override Swing's default and it will be invoked automatically from it's parent, `Panel`.

You must set your new component's size using `setSize`. Exact location of `msgBox` depends on your `Panel`'s layout. It can be set explicitly with `setLocation`, if `Panel`'s layout is `null`, or you may use one of more comfortable layouts.

As a side note, i recommend you to use some sort of a visual editor, such as an [Eclipse's VE](http://www.eclipse.org/vep/) plugin.

See the followin working example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SwingTestPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, FocusListener {
    MyMessageBox    msgBox    = new MyMessageBox();

    public SwingTestPanel(){
        initialize();
        addMouseListener(this);
        addFocusListener(this);
    }

    private void initialize(){
        this.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(new Dimension(446, 265));
        this.add(msgBox);
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe){
        System.out.println("Focus gained in JPanel");
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe){
        System.out.println("Focus lost in JPanel");
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){
        requestFocus();
        System.out.println("Mouse Pressed in JPanel");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me){}

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me){}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me){}

    static class MyMessageBox extends JComponent implements FocusListener, MouseListener {
        MyMessageBox(){
            initialize();
            addMouseListener(this);
            addFocusListener(this);
            System.out.println("Done");
        }

        private void initialize(){
            this.setName("msgBox");
            this.setEnabled(true);
            this.setSize(100, 100);
            this.setLocation(new Point(150, 100));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){
            requestFocus();
            System.out.println("Mouse pressed on box");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me){}

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){}

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me){}

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me){}

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe){
            System.out.println("Focus gained by box");
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe){
            System.out.println("Focus lost by box");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        SwingTestPanel content = new SwingTestPanel();
        window.setContentPane(content);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLocation(100, 75);
        window.setSize(400, 400);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
class Panel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, FocusListener {
    myMessageBox msgBox;

    public Panel() {
        addMouseListener(this);
        addFocusListener(this);
        msgBox = new myMessageBox();
        setLayout(null);
        add(msgBox);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
        System.out.println("Focus gained in JPanel");
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
        System.out.println("Focus lost in JPanel");
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        requestFocus();
        System.out.println("Mouse Pressed in JPanel");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        Panel content = new Panel();
        window.setContentPane(content);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLocation(100, 75);
        window.setSize(400, 400);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class myMessageBox extends JComponent implements FocusListener, MouseListener {
    myMessageBox() {
        addMouseListener(this);
        addFocusListener(this);
        System.out.println("Done");
        setBounds(150, 100, 100, 100);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Rectangle r = getBounds();
        Color saveColor = g.getColor();
        try {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, r.width, r.height);
        } finally {
            g.setColor(saveColor);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        requestFocus();
        System.out.println("Mouse pressed on box");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
        System.out.println("Focus gained by box");
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
        System.out.println("Focus lost by box");
    }
}
```